# Changing Texture color map in the fragment shader using UBO

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, webgl2

I am trying to change the color mapping of a texture once passed to the fragment shader but I am straggling with a sort of saturation issue is some areas of the produced texture.

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
        
precision mediump float;

in vec2 vTextureCoord;

// UBO
layout(std140) uniform colormap {
    float[256] r;
    float[256] g;
    float[256] b;
};

uniform sampler2D uSampler0;
uniform float uFactor0; 
out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    vec4 color0 = texture(uSampler0, vTextureCoord);
    
    int x = int(round(color0.x * 255.0));
    float px = r[x]/255.0;
    
    int y = int(round(color0.y * 255.0));
    float py = g[y]/255.0;
    
    int z = int(round(color0.z * 255.0));
    float pz = b[z]/255.0;

    fragColor = vec4(px, py, pz, 1.0);
}
```

In the Javascript code I have the following colorMap (I've extracted only the part needed):

```
class ColorMap {

   MYCOLORMAP = {
        "r": new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 12.0, 18.0, 24.0, 30.0, 36.0, 42.0, 48.0, 54.0, 60.0, 66.0, 72.0, 78.0, 85.0, 91.0, 97.0, 103.0, 109.0, 115.0, 121.0, 127.0, 133.0, 139.0, 145.0, 151.0, 157.0, 163.0, 170.0, 176.0, 182.0, 188.0, 194.0, 200.0, 206.0, 212.0, 218.0, 224.0, 230.0, 236.0, 242.0, 248.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 251.0, 247.0, 244.0, 240.0, 236.0, 233.0, 229.0, 226.0, 222.0, 218.0, 215.0, 211.0, 208.0, 204.0, 200.0, 197.0, 193.0, 190.0, 186.0, 182.0, 179.0, 175.0, 172.0, 168.0, 164.0, 161.0, 157.0, 154.0, 150.0, 146.0, 143.0, 139.0, 136.0, 132.0, 128.0, 125.0, 121.0, 118.0, 114.0, 110.0, 107.0, 103.0, 100.0]),
        "g": new Float32Array([0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 13.0, 16.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0, 26.0, 29.0, 32.0, 34.0, 37.0, 40.0, 42.0, 45.0, 48.0, 50.0, 53.0, 56.0, 58.0, 61.0, 64.0, 66.0, 69.0, 72.0, 74.0, 77.0, 80.0, 82.0, 85.0, 88.0, 90.0, 93.0, 96.0, 98.0, 101.0, 104.0, 106.0, 109.0, 112.0, 114.0, 117.0, 119.0, 122.0, 124.0, 127.0, 129.0, 132.0, 134.0, 137.0, 139.0, 142.0, 144.0, 147.0, 150.0, 152.0, 155.0, 157.0, 160.0, 162.0, 165.0, 167.0, 170.0, 172.0, 175.0, 177.0, 180.0, 182.0, 185.0, 188.0, 190.0, 193.0, 195.0, 198.0, 200.0, 203.0, 205.0, 208.0, 210.0, 213.0, 215.0, 218.0, 221.0, 221.0, 221.0, 222.0, 222.0, 222.0, 223.0, 223.0, 224.0, 224.0, 224.0, 225.0, 225.0, 225.0, 226.0, 226.0, 227.0, 227.0, 227.0, 228.0, 228.0, 229.0, 229.0, 229.0, 230.0, 230.0, 230.0, 231.0, 231.0, 232.0, 232.0, 232.0, 233.0, 233.0, 233.0, 234.0, 234.0, 235.0, 235.0, 235.0, 236.0, 236.0, 237.0, 235.0, 234.0, 233.0, 231.0, 230.0, 229.0, 227.0, 226.0, 225.0, 223.0, 222.0, 221.0, 219.0, 218.0, 217.0, 215.0, 214.0, 213.0, 211.0, 210.0, 209.0, 207.0, 206.0, 205.0, 203.0, 202.0, 201.0, 199.0, 198.0, 197.0, 195.0, 194.0, 193.0, 191.0, 190.0, 189.0, 187.0, 186.0, 185.0, 183.0, 182.0, 181.0, 180.0, 177.0, 175.0, 172.0, 170.0, 167.0, 165.0, 162.0, 160.0, 157.0, 155.0, 152.0, 150.0, 147.0, 145.0, 142.0, 140.0, 137.0, 135.0, 132.0, 130.0, 127.0, 125.0, 122.0, 120.0, 117.0, 115.0, 112.0, 110.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 100.0, 97.0, 95.0, 92.0, 90.0, 87.0, 85.0, 82.0, 80.0, 77.0, 75.0, 73.0, 71.0, 69.0, 68.0, 66.0, 64.0, 62.0, 61.0, 59.0, 57.0, 55.0, 54.0, 52.0, 50.0, 48.0, 47.0, 45.0, 43.0, 41.0, 40.0, 38.0, 36.0, 34.0, 33.0, 31.0, 29.0, 27.0, 26.0, 24.0, 22.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 15.0, 13.0, 12.0, 10.0, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0]),
        "b": new Float32Array([255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 254.0, 253.0, 252.0, 251.0, 250.0, 249.0, 248.0, 247.0, 246.0, 245.0, 245.0, 244.0, 243.0, 242.0, 241.0, 240.0, 239.0, 238.0, 237.0, 236.0, 236.0, 235.0, 234.0, 233.0, 232.0, 231.0, 230.0, 229.0, 228.0, 227.0, 226.0, 226.0, 225.0, 224.0, 223.0, 222.0, 221.0, 220.0, 219.0, 218.0, 217.0, 217.0, 211.0, 206.0, 201.0, 196.0, 191.0, 186.0, 181.0, 176.0, 171.0, 166.0, 161.0, 156.0, 151.0, 146.0, 141.0, 136.0, 131.0, 126.0, 121.0, 116.0, 111.0, 105.0, 100.0, 95.0, 90.0, 85.0, 80.0, 75.0, 70.0, 65.0, 60.0, 55.0, 50.0, 45.0, 40.0, 35.0, 30.0, 25.0, 20.0, 15.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    }
...
}
```

Below is the way I am setting up offsets and index of the UBO:

```
const blockIndex = global.gl.getUniformBlockIndex(this.shaderProgram, "colormap");
const blockSize = global.gl.getActiveUniformBlockParameter(
    this.shaderProgram,
    blockIndex,
    global.gl.UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE
);
const uboVariableNames = ["r", "g", "b"];
const uboVariableIndices = global.gl.getUniformIndices(
    this.shaderProgram,
    uboVariableNames
);
const uboVariableOffsets = global.gl.getActiveUniforms(
    this.shaderProgram,
    uboVariableIndices,
    global.gl.UNIFORM_OFFSET
);

this.uboBuffer = global.gl.createBuffer();

global.gl.bindBuffer(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, this.uboBuffer);

global.gl.bufferData(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, blockSize, global.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

global.gl.bindBuffer(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, null);

global.gl.bindBufferBase(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, this.uboBuffer);

let self = this;
uboVariableNames.forEach((name, index) => {
    self.uboVariableInfo[name] = {
        index: uboVariableIndices[index],
        offset: uboVariableOffsets[index],
    };
});
```

Later in the code, into the draw() method I retrieve the UBO and I fill it:

```
draw() {
    
    ...
    global.gl.bindBuffer(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, this.uboBuffer);
    global.gl.bindBufferBase(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, this.uboBuffer);
    global.gl.bufferSubData(
        global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER,
        this.uboVariableInfo["r"].offset,
        ColorMap.MYCOLORMAP.r,
        0
    );
    global.gl.bufferSubData(
        global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER,
        this.uboVariableInfo["g"].offset,
        ColorMap.MYCOLORMAP.g,
        0
    );
    global.gl.bufferSubData(
        global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER,
        this.uboVariableInfo["b"].offset,
        ColorMap.MYCOLORMAP.b,
        0
    );
    global.gl.bindBuffer(global.gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, null);
    ...

}
```

Just for clarify, when I show the texture with its native colors, I use another fragment shader.

The issue I am experiencing is when I pass MYCOLORMAP to the fragment shader above. The texture changes color, yes, but it looks totally black in some regions where it shouldn't be.
I am wondering if the error is that I am passing in a wrong way the data to the UBO not considering that probably Float32Array from MYCOLORMAP should be converted into half precision float or something like that to match GLSL float data type.

Anybody has any hint or can explain me where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've been able to sort it out.
As stated in the stt140 [enter link description here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381)

if you are handling array of int, float of boolean to be passed via UBO to the shader, than each value of the array mast be padded in order match the size of a vec4.

In my case, I've changed my MYCOLORMAP r, g and b array values by padding each value with (,0.0,0.0,0.0) and everything worked:

```
MYCOLORMAP = {
    "r": new Float32Array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 24.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 30.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 36.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 42.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 48.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 54.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 60.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 66.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 72.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 78.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 85.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 91.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 97.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 103.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 109.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 115.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 121.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 127.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 133.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 139.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 145.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 151.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 157.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 163.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 170.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 176.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 182.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 188.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 194.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 200.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 206.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 212.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 218.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 224.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 242.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 248.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 251.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 247.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 244.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 240.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 218.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 215.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 211.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 208.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 204.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 200.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 197.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 193.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 190.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 186.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 182.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 179.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 175.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 172.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 168.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 164.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 161.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 157.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 154.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 150.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 146.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 143.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 139.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 136.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 132.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 128.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 125.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 121.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 118.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 114.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 110.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 107.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 103.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
    "g": new Float32Array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 8.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 13.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 16.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 21.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 24.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 26.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 29.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 32.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 34.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 37.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 40.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 42.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 45.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 48.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 53.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 56.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 58.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 61.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 64.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 66.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 69.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 72.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 74.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 77.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 80.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 82.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 85.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 88.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 90.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 93.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 98.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 101.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 104.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 106.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 109.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 112.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 114.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 117.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 119.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 122.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 124.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 127.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 129.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 132.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 134.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 137.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 139.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 142.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 144.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 147.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 150.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 152.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 155.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 157.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 160.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 162.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 165.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 167.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 170.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 172.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 175.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 177.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 180.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 182.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 185.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 188.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 190.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 193.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 195.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 198.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 200.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 203.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 205.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 208.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 210.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 213.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 215.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 218.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 221.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 221.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 221.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 223.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 223.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 224.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 224.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 224.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 225.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 225.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 225.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 227.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 227.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 227.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 228.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 228.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 231.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 231.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 232.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 232.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 232.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 234.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 234.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 235.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 235.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 235.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 237.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 235.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 234.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 231.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 227.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 225.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 223.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 221.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 219.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 218.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 217.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 215.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 214.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 213.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 211.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 210.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 209.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 207.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 206.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 205.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 203.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 202.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 201.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 199.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 198.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 197.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 195.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 194.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 193.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 191.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 190.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 189.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 187.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 186.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 185.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 183.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 182.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 181.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 180.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 177.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 175.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 172.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 170.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 167.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 165.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 162.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 160.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 157.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 155.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 152.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 150.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 147.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 145.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 142.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 140.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 137.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 135.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 132.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 130.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 127.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 125.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 122.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 120.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 117.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 115.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 112.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 110.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 107.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 105.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 102.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 97.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 95.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 92.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 90.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 87.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 85.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 82.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 80.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 77.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 75.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 73.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 71.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 69.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 68.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 66.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 64.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 62.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 61.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 59.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 57.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 55.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 54.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 52.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 48.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 47.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 45.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 43.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 41.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 40.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 38.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 36.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 34.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 33.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 31.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 29.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 27.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 26.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 24.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 22.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 19.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 17.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 15.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 13.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 12.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 8.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 3.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
    "b": new Float32Array([255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 255.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 254.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 253.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 252.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 251.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 250.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 249.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 248.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 247.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 246.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 245.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 245.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 244.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 243.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 242.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 241.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 240.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 239.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 238.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 237.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 235.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 234.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 233.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 232.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 231.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 230.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 229.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 228.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 227.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 226.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 225.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 224.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 223.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 222.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 221.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 220.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 219.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 218.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 217.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 217.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 211.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 206.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 201.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 196.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 191.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 186.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 181.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 176.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 171.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 166.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 161.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 156.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 151.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 146.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 141.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 136.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 131.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 126.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 121.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 116.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 111.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 105.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 95.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 90.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 85.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 80.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 75.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 70.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 65.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 60.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 55.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 45.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 40.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 35.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 30.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 25.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 15.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
}
```